# When I am trying to fetch broken links of a webpage not getting all of them in webdriver java

Tags: java, webdriver, broken-links

All links are not fetching among total 210 links.and only 2 links are getting fetched in output

```
List <WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println("Total no of liks are: "+ links.size());
for (int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
{
WebElement element=links.get(i);
System.out.println(element);
String url=element.getAttribute("href");
URL myurl=new URL(url);
System.out.println(myurl);
HttpURLConnection httpconn= (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
Thread.sleep(3000);
httpconn.connect();
int rescode=httpconn.getResponseCode();
if(rescode>=400)
{
System.out.println(rescode + "This is broken link");
}
else
{
System.out.println(rescode + "This is not a broken link");  
}
}
```

Comment: also the code snippet i used :for (int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
  {
   WebElement element=links.get(i);
   
   System.out.println(element);
   String url=element.getAttribute("href");
   
   URL myurl=new URL(url);
   
   System.out.println(myurl);
   
   //create connection of myurl object 
   
   HttpURLConnection httpconn= (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
   //establish connection
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   httpconn.connect();
   
   
   //return response if response is abobe 400
   
   int rescode=httpconn.getResponseCode();

Comment: Please edit your question and the snippet code in the related text area by using code button (the symbol is {}).

Comment: While fetching the links in a webpage using java webdriver methods, it is showing 210 links are there. but when trying to fetch both the broken links and other links which are not broken by using if else condition getting only 2 out f 210. my question is why it is so..where i am making wrong in it..i am new in java and webdriver aswell. please refer my code snippet in my next comment

Comment: List <WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println("Total no of liks are: "+ links.size());
for (int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
{
WebElement element=links.get(i);
System.out.println(element);
String url=element.getAttribute("href");
URL myurl=new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection httpconn= (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
Thread.sleep(3000);
httpconn.connect();
int rescode=httpconn.getResponseCode();
if(rescode>=400)
{
System.out.println(rescode + "This is broken link");
}
else
{
System.out.println(rescode + "This is not a broken link"); 
}
}